# Forcing laptop to use integrated graphics so that Nvidia GPU can be used for CUDA computing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Dell Precision 3541 laptop with Nvidia Quadro P620, using Ubuntu 20.04 and CUDA 11.4. In order to accomplish GPU computing for deep learning tasks, I must:

```
sudo prime-select intel
sudo reboot
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Which forces Xorg to use the Intel integrated graphics upon reboot, and then `sudo prime-select nvidia` makes the GPU visible for deep learning applications. The problem is that if a reboot occurs without issuing `sudo prime-select intel` beforehand, then the nvidia card is used for Xorg which makes it unusable for deep learning tasks.

Is there a way to make the nvidia card visible for deep learning tasks without making it the default Xorg output?